# LinkedIn example code gives SyntaxError

Tags: javascript, jquery, linkedin-api

Trying to follow a [linkedin example](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/creating-member-profile-plugin) but their code does not seem to work

When I copy the example code into a HTML page it gets rendered as this

```
 Profile App Example

'); IN.parse(document.getElementById("profile")) }) }
```

I get this error in firebug

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
[Break On This Error]   

e="IN/FullMemberProfile" data-id="' + result.values[0].id + '">
```

but I am not seeing it(in the example code it looks like all the quotes match).

Also get this error

```
TypeError: $.cookie is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

...kie('quck-note-current', JSON.stringify({ "Id": id, "Note": note }), { expires: ...
```

**Edit**

Here is the full example code they have.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Profile App Example</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
  api_key: o1yf9WMdgd8dp_OGkmtXESCOJFostN8N1jI1AFKY2i0kJ1QFNMOs3a6R5qUoBIqF
  authorize: true
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5b1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>  

<script type="text/javascript">

function loadData() {
IN.API.Profile("me")
   .result(function(result) { 
      $("#profile").html('<script type="IN/FullMemberProfile" data-id="' + result.values[0].id + '"></script>');
      IN.parse(document.getElementById("profile"))
   })
}

</script>

</head>
<body class="yui3-skin-sam     yui-skin-sam">
<div id="profile"></div>
<script type="IN/Login" data-onAuth="loadData"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit 2**

I tried using their api key and I used my api key(what is for some reason alot shorter than their example on but that is what it is showing in the app area under api key)

Comment: Your first error is obvious: your line starts with a single quote, but is not closed with one. However, this looks like you've not cut and paste your example properly, and missed some code as a result. For your second error - have you loaded jQuery?

Comment: `unterminated string literal` means you've probably got a copy-pasta error and missed a `'` or `"` somewhere.

Comment: @MikeW - I copied and pasted directly from their site. From the code it looks like all quotes match. Please highlight where it is not matching as I am not seeing it.

Comment: I looked at their site too. The first three characters on your line come from the previous line in their example. As I said: "your line **starts** with a single quote...". Try looking at the **start** of the line...

Comment: Can you highlight in the example code that I posted what is going wrong. The first piece of code I have is the "result" what I see on the page. The line gets broken and displays some of it. The code I am using is a direct paste from their site and is in the Edit section of this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery removes the script tag when using `$(string)`.

This line:

```
$("#profile").html('<script type="IN/FullMemberProfile" data-id="' + result.values[0].id + '"></script>');
```

needs to have `</script>` becoming `<\/script>`, which is why the error was found just before:

```
'); IN.parse(document.getElementById("profile")) }) }
```

Similar discussion: [How to get JavaScript script tags inside jQuery .html() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654233/how-to-get-javascript-script-tags-inside-jquery-html-function)